# How do I see the default values of a table and its columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that have default values for a column. How do I actually see the actual default values for each column ? Is it location in `Information_Schema` anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

You ca get it from `sys.columns`

```
SELECT object_definition(default_object_id) AS default_value
FROM sys.columns
WHERE name ='col_name'
AND object_id = object_id('table_name')
```

If you want it for all of your columns, exclude the column name from you `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is:

```
select TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_DEFAULT from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'yourtablename'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these,

This will give you every details of the table's structure.

```
EXEC sp_columns @table_name = N'Department', @table_owner = 'HumanResources';
```

See more about [sp_columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176077.aspx).

Or you can use,

```
SELECT so.name AS table_name, 
          sc.name AS column_name, 
          sm.text AS default_value
     FROM sys.sysobjects so
     JOIN sys.syscolumns sc ON sc.id = so.id
LEFT JOIN sys.syscomments SM ON sm.id = sc.cdefault
    WHERE so.xtype = 'U' 
      AND so.name = @yourtable
 ORDER BY so.[name], sc.colid
```